# Undefined variable: config. PHP error but email is sent

Tags: php, codeigniter

Greetings!

I just downloaded version 2.0.1 of CodeIgniter framework and I am attempting to write my own email controller like so:

```
<?php

class Email extends CI_Controller
{
     function __construct()     {         parent::__construct();     } 

    function index()     {   
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from('some.email@gmail.com', 'some.email.name');
        $this->email->to('some.author.email.@gmail.com');        
        $this->email->subject('This is an email test');        
        $this->email->message('It is working!');

        $path = $this->config->item('server_root');        

        $file = $path . '/attachments/readme.txt';

        $this->email->attach($file);

        if($this->email->send())         {             echo 'Email sent.';         }        
        else        {            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());        }
    }
}
```

If I point my browser to "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/email", I get this PHP error message

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: config
Filename: controllers/email.php
Line Number: 24
```

The line number 24 points to this line of code in my controller **$this->load->library('email', $config)**;

In spite of the PHP error, email is being sent fine, with a file attachment.

How can I remove this PHP error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A notice is just an informational "hey, here's something you may want to look at sometime". It's not an error or an "zomg someone set us up the bomb!". They can be ignored, but should be dealt with for "complete" correctness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the message states, $config is not defined. You could fix it by defining it.

`$config = Array();`

somewhere before line 24 should do it

Comment: You are welcome. Sometimes it's the most obvious stuff that baffles us, no one is immune to that ;)

Answer (score 3):

No you should not fix it by defining it, that is incorrect.

You need to change

```
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

to

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

The array does not exist because you have set the configuration details in your config/email.php file so the $config array is not required AGAIN. :)

Comment: Thats nice as we have loaded the configuration details in email.php we can just load it to get the access of email object

Answer (score 0):

$config = Array();
I you initialize it like this than your array be will empty so you have no need to 
define array when you load library configuration properties will configured automatically. No need to pass $config variable only do this
$this->load->library('email'); it will work fine for u.